# Pass item array variable to Get-Content

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I'm trying to remove the first 3 lines of an item array in PowerShell and pass it to a file.

I can get it working but only if I create two files:

```
$myData = Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "SELECT PersonID FROM tblPerson" -ServerInstance $ServerAddress -Database $DatabaseName;

$myData | Out-file -Force $PersonIDList
Get-Content $PersonIDList | Select-Object -Skip 3 | Out-File $PersonIDList2;

Write-Host "[+] PersonList file overwritten";
```

That works, but I just wanted to find a better and more elegant way of doing it. Ive tried various things such as:

```
Get-Content $myData | Select-Object -Skip 3 | Out-File
```

```
$($myData.ItemArray[0:$myData.count]) | Out-File
```

And a lot more, all failed.

Comment: `$myData = $myData | Select-Object -Skip 3` ?

Comment: Alternatively: `$myData[3..$($myData.Count-1)] | Out-File ...`

Comment: Thanks for the responses, I figured it out shortly after that I needed to use .. instead of :

Comment: I'm using the second approach  $($myData.ItemArray[0..$myData.count]) | Out-file but both work well, thanks